# Internal rounding woes: accurate way to sum Ruby floating point numbers?

Tags: ruby

This is of course broken:

```
(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1) => 0.30000000000000004

(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1) == 0.3   # false
```

I don't need a perfect sum, just good enough to say two Floats are the same value. The best I can figure out is to multiply both sides of the equation and round. Is this the best way?

```
((0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1) * 1000).round == (0.3 * 1000).round
```

UPDATE: I'm stuck on Ruby v1.8.7.

Comment: Floating-point comparations are usually done via `if abs(v1-v2)<epsilon` where "epsilon" is a decently small constant like 1.0e-6. I don't know the syntax for Ruby, so you'll have to adapt this yourself.

Comment: Actually. That is probably the better short answer I've heard yet: ((0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1) - 0.3).abs < 0.0001

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between summing accurately and comparing effectively.  You say you want the former, but it looks like you want the later.  The underlying Ruby float arithmetic is IEEE and has sensible semantics for minimizing accumulated error, but there always will be when using a representation that can't exactly represent all values.  To accurately model error, FP addition shouldn't produce an exact value, it should produce an interval and further additions will operate on intervals.

In practice, many applications don't need to have detailed accounting for error, they just need to do their calculation and be aware that comparisons aren't exact and output decimal representations should be rounded.

Here's a simple extension to Float that will help you out with comparison. It or something like it should be in the stdlib, but ain't.

```
class Float
  def near_enough?(other, epsilon = 1e-6)
    (self - other.to_f).abs < epsilon.to_f
  end
end

pry(main)> (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1).near_enough?(0.3)
=> true
pry(main)> (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1).near_enough?(0.3, 1e-17)
=> false
pry(main)> ( [0.1] * (10**6) ).reduce(:+).near_enough?(10**5, 1e-5)
=> true
pry(main)> ( [0.1] * (10**6) ).reduce(:+).near_enough?(10**5)
=> false
```

Picking an appropriate `epsilon` can be tricky in the general case.  You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). I've found Bruce Dawson's floating point tricks blogs excellent, here's his chapter on [Comparing Floating Point Numbers](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/02/22/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/)

If you really are concerned about accuracy, you could do your arithmetic using an exact representation.  Ruby supplies a [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/rational/rdoc/Rational.html) class (even back in 1.8) which let's you do exact arithmetic on fractions.

```
pry(main)> r=Rational(1,10)
=> (1/10)
pry(main)> (r + r + r) == Rational(3,10)
=> true
pry(main)> (r + r + r) == 0.3
=> true
pry(main)> r.to_f
=> 0.1
pry(main)> (r + r + r).to_f
=> 0.3
```

Comment: Don't neglect to mention that you can use Float::EPSILON as well. [Refactored your near_enough?](https://gist.github.com/kotp/5173308) method like so.

Comment: @vgoff `Float::EPSILON` is not a good general purpose epsilon. [For numbers between 1.0 and 2.0 FLT_EPSILON represents the difference between adjacent floats. For numbers smaller than 1.0 an epsilon of FLT_EPSILON quickly becomes too large, and with small enough numbers FLT_EPSILON may be bigger than the numbers you are comparing](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/02/22/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/)

Comment: I don't know if that is your blog, but as stated, many things to consider, and definitely did not consider less than 1.0.  If I must compare floats, I generally try to determine the level of precision and compare the difference is between some margin of error.  Still haven't found my favorite way to do this though.  Thanks for the blog post link.

Answer (score -1):

The round method supports the specification of decimal places to which to round: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round

So

```
 (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1).round(1) == (0.3).round(1)
```

... ought to be good.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm stuck on Ruby 1.8.7 in this case.

Comment: `backports` gem should bring it there.